# puppet module not doing anything

Tags: java, puppet

I successfully installed the puppetlabs java module using command `puppet module install puppetlabs-java`.

I created a puppet module using command `puppet module generate ...`

I have two manifest files `init.pp` and `java.pp`. Later i will have more.

**init.pp**

```
class mystuff {
  anchor { 'mystuff::begin': }
  -> class { 'mystuff::java': }
  -> anchor { 'mystuff::end': }
}
```

**java.pp**

```
class mystuff::java(){
  class { 'java':
    package => 'java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel'
  }
}
```

I then build the puppet module using command `puppet module build`.

I then installed the module using command `puppet module install ~/.../pkg/...-0.1.0.tar.gz`.

My idea was to test it with a new manifest file so i created a file called `test-it.pp`.

**test-it.pp**

```
class { 'mystuff': }
```

I then called `puppet apply ./test-it.pp`. And i get the following logo output:

```
Warning: /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/hiera.yaml: Use of 'hiera.yaml' version 3 is deprecated. It should be converted to version 5
   (in /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/hiera.yaml)
Notice: Compiled catalog for masternode.mydomain.com in environment production in 0.15 seconds
Notice: /Stage[main]/Java/Package[java]/ensure: created
Notice: /Stage[main]/Java::Config/File_line[java-home-environment]/ensure: created
Notice: Applied catalog in 7.72 seconds
```

But now when i go to my slave node and i type `java` it says `command not found`.

What did i do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

OK i found the solution or understood what i did wrong.
First of all i tried to invoke the puppet installation on the master node. By running `puppet apply ./test-it.pp`. Since this did not work i tried to invoke it on the slave node using `sudo /opt/puppetlabs/bin/puppet agent -t` instead.

For this to be working i renamed the `test-it.pp` to `site.pp` and moved it to `/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/manifests/`.

It took some seconds and now i can use java on the slave node like expected.